# Grails, Spring Security and Angular JS - How to protect URLs?

Tags: rest, angularjs, grails, spring-security

Hello I build application with backend built in Grails and frontend made in AngularJS. I want to use Grails Spring Security Plugin to give some security to my app, but I've got some problems with that. First off all, I don't know how to allow only users with specified role to access dedicated URLs.

For example I have 3 types of URLs

```
/userspace/**  - (eg. http://localhost:8080/MyApp/#/userspace/settings -displays view with user's profile settings)
/adminspace/** - (eg. http://localhost:8080/MyApp/#/adminspace/usersManagement - displays view with registered users) 
/rest/** - (eg. http://localhost:8080/MyApp/rest/book - returns JSON list of books, http://localhost:8080/MyApp/book/123 - returns book as JSON with id=123.
```

I would like to give access to `/userspace/` for `ROLE_USER` and to `/adminspace/` for `ROLE_ADMIN`.

I don't know what properties should I set in `Config.goovy` to make it possible? Have angular's `#` in url any matter?

I'm also not sure how should I protect `/rest/**`. These urls are used to communicate with backend and sometimes they are called by angular's `$http` service from angular's controllers of views visible to all, but sometimes they are called from protected views. Maybe the way is to leave /rest/** urls available for all and use specified annotations eg. `@Secured(['ROLE_USER'])` in grails controllers?

I would be grateful for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is discussed here (not specific to Angular of course): http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/docs/manual/guide/requestMappings.html

If you have annotated controllers, map these extra URLs in the `controllerAnnotations.staticRules` map. Otherwise use Requestmaps in the database, or one big map in the `interceptUrlMap` property.

Comment: Thanks it works. I don't know if it is a mistake, but Spring Security documentation says that I should use: `grails.plugin.springsecurity.controllerAnnotations.staticRules`. It didn't work until I've changed it to `grails.plugins.springsecurity.controllerAnnotations.staticRules`. Maybe it would be helpful for someone.

Comment: I wasn't sure what version of the plugin you're using. The link I had was for the 2.0 plugin, but the 1.2 docs are at http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/docs/manual.1273/guide/5%20Configuring%20Request%20Mappings%20to%20Secure%20URLs.html