# How to secure REST API in Grails using Spring Security?

Tags: grails, spring-security

I have an Grails application where I have few REST API which is consumed by my mobile client and a admin web app, I have to provide form based security for the web app and for each REST service call client would send a token, which I generate when client calls authenticate by passing username and password.

For that I have used Spring Security plugin for Grails, so my admin app is secured as expected. But how can I secure my REST API, Ideally I would like to put @Secured(['ROLE_API']) for all the REST API.

Comment: Usually it's done through OAuth2 - https://github.com/adaptivecomputing/grails-spring-security-oauth2-provider

Answer (score 0):

You could add `/rest/` at beginning of all your RESTSs URLs and then in `Config.groovy` add

```
grails.plugins.springsecurity.controllerAnnotations.staticRules = [
        '/': ['permitAll'],
        '/rest/**': ['ROLE_API'],
]
```

I had similar problem here: [Grails, Spring Security and Angular JS - How to protect URLs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20009580/grails-spring-security-and-angular-js-how-to-protect-urls)

Check also the Spring Security manual http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/ section *Configuring Request Mappings to Secure URLs*

Comment: @Kimi, I think rule '/**' matches everything. Am i right? In my app I have rules: '/' ['permitAll'], '/admin/**': ['ROLE_ADMIN'] and it  works fine. I don't have access to anything with "/admin" in url without login.